# Time Picker Jquery onchange and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I'm using this timepicker for my page.

https://engel-ja.github.io/picktim/

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Time-Selector-Picktim/

```
jQ(".timepicker").picktim({ mode: 'h24' });
```

how do i get the **onchange** event to work on the timepicker and get its **time value**.

[image: onchange event with time value]

As their is **no option tutorial** given by the author for it.

Comment: did you try the "normal" way? eg `jQ(document).on('change','.timepicker',function(){...})`

Comment: Not working @johnSmith any other way

Comment: Choose another datepicker library, i went through the code and saw no easy implementation

Comment: ok @johnSmith can you suggest any other jquery time picker.. with the onchange and value get .. similar to this one.

Comment: found a solution for it @johnSmith jQ("i.picktim-btn").on("click", function () {
            var b = $('.timepicker input').val();
            console.log(b);
        });

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a jquery in the document ready function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input').on('change',function(){
    console.log($(this));
     if($(this).hasClass('picktim-mins') || $(this).hasClass('picktim-hour')){
         alert($(this).val());
        }
     
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap dateTimePicker. It has good community support and documentation.

[Bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: i was using that but as per client expectation they require a little easy with time picker independently.